# javax.jms.ResourceAllocationException: MQJMS2008 error when injecting 512th message

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I get the following exception when I am injecting messages into queue, which happens everytime when I inject the 512th message, the previous 511 are injected fine:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.ResourceAllocationException: MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue 'xxxx.xx.xxxxx.xxxx'.
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getQueueOpenException(MQQueueServices.java:907)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQQueueServices.getOutputQueue(MQQueueServices.java:726)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.JMSServicesMgr.getOutputQueue(JMSServicesMgr.java:210)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createQProducer(MQSession.java:3173)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2896)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.createProducer(MQSession.java:2953)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1302)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createSender(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:131)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createSender(MQQueueSession.java:148)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createProducer(MQQueueSession.java:249)
at com.connect.MQAction.injectMessage(MQAction.java:45)
at pricecheck.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

What is the reason for this error?

I am using the following method to inject a message everytime:

```
public void injectMessage(String content) throws JMSException, IOException {
    MessageProducer producer = queueSession.createProducer(queue);
    Message msg = queueSession.createTextMessage(content);
    producer.send(msg);
}
```

Is it due to me creating a MessageProducer everytime?

Answer (score 1):

To know for sure we need the 'cause by' linked exception. But you're more than likely hitting some sort of resource limit as you have a **major** resource leak in that you create a MessageProducer each time the function is invoked, but never close it!

Add 'producer.close()' to the end of the function, preferably in a finally block, or even better create the producer once and simply use it each time the function is invoked. Creating a MessageProducer is an expensive operation so do it as little as possible to get the best performance possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it due to me creating a MessageProducer everytime?

Why would you do that?  Why not reuse the MessageProducer?